# Bootstrap-select in responsive table, page always scroll up

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I have a bootstrap-select inside a td of a table-responsive table. If I click on the select-picker, dropdown menu is not entirely visibile (visibility is limited by table margin). If I add data-container="body" (or another element in data-container, as official guidelines), page automatically go on top and every time I have to scroll down up to the table (with dropdown correctly opened and visible).

```html
<div class="table-responsive">  
  <table class="table" id="table">     
    <thead>
      <tr class="d-flex">
      <!-- others -->    
    </thead>    
    <tbody id="participants">
     <!-- others -->
      <td class="col-3">
        <select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true">
        <!-- options -->
        </select>
      </td>    
     </tbody>   
   </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem! Were you able to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't follow the bootstrap and table structures. I replaced the modified code:

```html
<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-sm">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">
                <select class="selectpicker form-control" multiple data-live-search="true">
                    <option>one</option>
                    <option>two</option>
                    <option>three</option>
                </select>
            </th>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I've modified the code with your suggestions. It's all ok on Safari, but I have the same issue on Google Chrome. The dropdown menu is entirely visible but, when I open it, page scroll automatically on top.

Comment: Yes of course, here the dropdown menu open https://ibb.co/5cN6ZqS

Comment: I can't understand your problem and need more explanation about it. if you can send more code and image.